# How do I edit the GKE auto-scaler settings?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I came across this page regarding the kube auto-scaler: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-are-the-parameters-to-ca

From this, I can tell that part of the reason why some of my nodes aren't being scaled down, is because they have local-data set on them...

By default, the auto-scaler ignores nodes that have local data. I want to change this to false. However, I can't find instructions anywhere about *how* to change it.

I can't find any obvious things to edit. There's nothing in `kube-system` that implies it is about the autoscaler configuration - just the autoscaler status ConfigMap.

Could somebody help please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. The only option the GKE gives is a vague "autoscaling profile" choice between the default and "optimize utilization". You can, however, override it with per-pod annotations.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment about the per-pod annotations helped me find this: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node  specifically, the example annotation. If you added that as an example it might help the answer more. thank you again!

Comment: Also. How annoying that we can't touch the configuration! Ah well